# Is there any way to make each div collapse separately?

Tags: html, spring, bootstrap-4, freemarker

A button is created for each question from the database, when clicked, only one answer should be opened. But instead, when you click on any of the buttons, all answers open.

So far I've tried to change "collapse" to "${question.id}", but it seems to me that it doesn't work this way.

```
<div class="card-columns">
    <#list questions as question>
        <div class="card border-light mb-3 bg-card">
            <div class="m-2">
                <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button"
                            data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target="#collapse"
                            aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-controls="collapse">
                        ${question.question}
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="m-2">
                <div class="collapse" id="collapse">
                    <div class="card card-body border-info">
                        ${question.answer}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <#else>
                There is no questions.
            </#list>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change "**collapse**" to $question.id in 2 line: 
`<button ... data-target="#collapse"`
and 
`<div ... id="collapse">`(**id** not class).
I dont familiar with freemarker, so cant provide full fix.

Comment: Remeber to keep "#" symbol in attribute data-target of button tag